# Gatling scala - read collection from file and send it as json

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a file with strings and I want to read from it every time X records. I have 2 questions:

1. Which type of file should I save my records? ("records.")
2. How can I read X records from my file and send them as json for HttpRequestBuilder as body? For example:

   ```
   val request: HttpRequestBuilder = Utils.createPostBodyRequest(
     "request",
     "localhost:8080/request",
     Map(Constants.Content_Type -> Constants.Application_Json),
     ElFileBody("records.json"))

   def createPostBodyRequest(reqName: String, url: String, 
                             headers: Map[String, String], body: Body): HttpRequestBuilder = {
      http(reqName)
       .post(url)
       .headers(headers)
       .body(body)
   }
   ```

Comment: If you make use of db like mongodb u can send me easily as a zip to the user and it will get downloaded to his browser

Comment: with file, the problem is, u will have to open it, read stuff from it, find next x records from the previous offset and then close the file read, zip the records and send it to the user.

Comment: @zenwraight In my case x=5 and I have only 15 records, so I can save it in csv or something like that. my question is HOW to tell him to take another attribute in every run ? its a load test so I want that will be automatically.

Comment: got it u are saying how to tell ur endpoint about the offset like in the first call u fetched 5 now in the second call fetch next 5 i.e from 5 to 10 and in the third call fetch 11 to 15. so that value u can send in ur request as offset value, like in the first call offset will be 0, in the second call offset will be 5 etc...

Comment: Also if possible can u share ur whole code here, then it will be easier to understand the flow

Answer (score 0):

you can use Feeders to inject data https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/feeder/#feeder 
Other ways to inject data : 
https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/session_api/#injecting-data